# How to make tree dictionary with Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I need some help with a Python problem I am having. I have some data from a MySQL database which I wants to make a parent/Child dictionary from.

The data I am retrieving contains two values a Name and size: So how do I go from these values to a dictionary as the one showed below.

```
{
    "name": " ",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "HSC",
            "size": 0.2,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "MPP",
                    "size": 15,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "CMP",
                            "size": 8,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "MEP",
                                    "size": 6
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "GMP",
                                    "size": 10,
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "early PM",
                                            "size": 2
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have writing some code:

```
cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT gene_data.gene_name, gene_data.mean FROM genes INNER JOIN gene_data ON genes.id = gene_data.g_id WHERE genes.name =  %s AND genes.type = %s  AND gene_data.probe_name = %s', (gene, types,  probe))

rows = cur.fetchall()
cmap = {}
for row in rows:
    entry = {'name': row[0], 'size': row[1], 'children':[]}
    cmap[row[0]] = entry

for index, row in enumerate(rows):
    item = cmap[row[0]]
    if((index+2)>len(rows)):
        parent = cmap.get( row[0], None )
        parent["children"].append(item.copy())
        if parent:
            parent["children"].append(item.copy)
            hrcy = parent["children"]
            print hrcy
    else:
        next = rows[index+1]
        nextItem = cmap[next[0]]
        parent = cmap.get( row[0], None )
        #parent["children"].append(nextItem.copy())
        if parent:
            parent["children"].append(nextItem.copy())
```

When I run this code I only gets one row. I need every row to be added to the previously children element.

Comment: Show us this 'some data'.

Comment: I have added the select statement, It returns a gene name and size.

Comment: THis SELECT will return a list. How are the entries of this list related? Why is one entry the child of another entry?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524902/recursive-function-for-trees-in-python may help you....

Comment: They are related to the order of the genes. the first gene is root. So when I select them I receive the order of the genes.