# Recursive TreeItems Search

Tags: python

I have `QTreeWidget` with nested parent-child items:

```
Tree:
    parent1:
           childA1
           childA2
           childA3:
                  childB1
                  childB2:
                         childC1
```

Using:

```
    allItems=[]
    for i in range(Tree.topLevelItemCount()):
        item=Tree.topLevelItem(i)
        allItems.add(item)
```

I access the first level items "A": `childA1, childA2 and childA3`.

Now I iterate each of the first level "A" items to access their children - the second level items "B":

```
    for i in range(Tree.topLevelItemCount()):
        item=Tree.topLevelItem(i)

        for m in range(item.childCount()):
            childItem=item.child(m)
            allItems.add(childItem)
```

Here at the second level I don't know if there are any third level items "C" below.
How to make sure the function advances down as deep as there are nested items below adding the items to `allItems` list till it reaches the end?

Comment: There are numerous answers covering recursion in the **Related** questions -->

Comment: Have you heard of breadth first search and depth-first search? Note that python has a recursion limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below creates `QTreeWidget` with nested items.

The Tree's `getItemsRecursively()` method scans the Tree till it reaches a bottom item returning a list of all items in a Tree.

## [image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        for name in ['Item_A0', 'Item_A1', 'Item_A2']: 
            itemA=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([name])

            self.addTopLevelItem(itemA)
            if name=='Item_A1':
                item_B0=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(['Item_B0'])
                itemA.insertChild(0, item_B0)
                itemA.insertChild(1, QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(['Item_B1']))

                item_C0=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(['Item_C0'])
                item_B0.insertChild(0, item_C0)
                item_B0.insertChild(0, QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(['Item_C1']))

        self.resize(360,240)
        self.show()

    def getItemsRecursively(self):
        total=[]
        def serchChildItem(item=None):
            if not item: return
            for m in range(item.childCount()): 
                childItem=item.child(m)                
                if not childItem: continue
                total.append(childItem)   
                serchChildItem(childItem)

        for i in range(self.topLevelItemCount()):
            item=self.topLevelItem(i)
            if not item: continue
            total.append(item)
            serchChildItem(item)
        return total

tree=Tree()
total=tree.getItemsRecursively()
print 'Total number of Tree items: %s'%len(total)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using recursive implementation especially since the requirement for depth of recursion seems to be quite low in your case.

Incase the height of your tree exceeds 1000, note that Python has a default recursion limit [ Which could be overriden by setting the limit via `sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)`, although it is discouraged to do so since CPython ( python's default implementation ) does not optimize deep recursions and hence the default limit ]

There are a lot of guides for such recursive implementations. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524902/recursive-function-for-trees-in-python) SO question here could be modded for your particular application.

Incase you would want a non recursive implementation, the below could work for your situation [ Note that I haven't tested the same ]. This is just so that you get an Idea.

```
allItems=[]
buff = []

# Populating the buffer with all the top level items
for i in range(Tree.topLevelItemCount()):
    item=Tree.topLevelItem(i)
    buff.append(item)

while len(buff) > 0:
    # Take the first item out of the buffer by popping it
    current_item = buff.pop(buff[0])

    # Put all the childs of current_item in the buffer
    for child_no in range(current_item.childCount):
        buff.append(current_item.child(child_no))

    # Append the current_item to the allItems list
    allItems.append(current_item)
```