# Call functions recursively in tree structure using python

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, tree, function-call

I need to call functions recursively in tree structure.

Below is the image for example tree structure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYWyj.png)

here I am calling the python function in in for loop by passing `A`, this will produce the output `B` in first loop and `C` in second loop.

here I need to run the same function for `B` and `C`, so here `B` will generate `D` and `E` and `C` will generate `F` and next Run same python function for `D` it will generate `G` so on, I have to run the same until I get null.

How can I write the logic in python

Comment: possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524902/recursive-function-for-trees-in-python

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways depending on the end goal really but this basic recursive function will traverse your whole tree.

```
def get_children(node):
    for child in node:
        get_children(child)
```

This structure will go all the way down the left branches of the tree first though. Might be worth noting.